# Streamlining Azure set up with app and DB on separate VMs

Tags: django, postgresql, azure, ubuntu

A Django app of mine (with a postgresql backend) is hosted over two separate Ubuntu VMs. I use Azure as my infrastructure provider, and the VMs are *classic*. Both are part of the same resource group, and map to the same DNS as well (i.e. they both live on `xyz.cloudapp.net`). Currently, I have the following database url defined in my app's settings.py:

```
DATABASE_URL = 'postgres://username:password@public_ip_address:5432/dbname'
```

The DB port 5432 is publicly open, and I'm assuming the above DB url implies the web app is connecting to the DB as if it's on a **remote machine**. If so, that's not the best practice: it has security repercussions, not to mention it adds anything from 20-30 milliseconds to a hundred milliseconds to each query (in latency).

My question is, how does one program such a Django+postgres setup on Azure such that the database is only exposed on the private network? I want to keep the two-VM set up intact. An illustrative example would be nice - I'm guessing I'll have to replace the public ip address in my settings.py with a private IP? I can see a private IP address listed under `Virtual machines(classic) > VMname > Settings > IP Addresses` in the Azure portal. Is this the one to use? If so, it's dynamically assigned, thus wouldn't it change after a while? Looking forward to guidance on this.

---

Comment: A follow up to the previous question? Not an expert on azure so can't tell you how they allocate private network IPS. However as to what port postgresql listens on, that's controlled by `listen_addresses` in `postgresql.conf`. By default that's just localhost. One widely used practice is to change it to something like `listen_addresses='localhost,192.168.1.1'`

Comment: @e4c5: Yes, I've been looking into this ever since the previous question, and this is indeed a followup. Currently I've set `listen_addresses = '*'` in `postgresql.conf`, which I'm assuming poses security issues?

Comment: Well, yes, better to have it like 'localhost,192.168.1.1'

Comment: Yep, will do once I solve my static private IP problems. Thanks for chiming in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Classic (ASM) mode, the Cloud Service is the network security boundary and the Endpoints with ACLs are used to restrict access from the outside Internet.

A simple solution to secure access would be:

- Ensure that the the DB port (5432) is removed from the cloud service endpoint (to avoid exposing it for the entire Internet).
- Get at *static private IP address* for the DB server.
- Use the private IP address of
  the DB server in the connection string.
- Keep the servers in the same Cloud Service.

You can find detailed instructions here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-classic-pportal/

This should work. But for future implementations, I would recommend the more modern Azure Resource Model (ARM), where you can benefit from many nice new features, including virtual networks (VNETs) where you get more fine-grained security.

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough. Appreciate it. The trouble for me is that on `portal.azure.com`, I can't seem to set my private IP static. I'm shown the prompt: **This virtual machine can't be configured with a static private IP address because it's not deployed in a virtual network**. I also looked at manage.windowsazure.com - I can't do it from there either. I thought resource group and virtual network were comparable.

Comment: The Xplat-CLI (cross platform command line client for management of azure) will probably do the job.  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-static-private-ip-classic-cli/